# Blower fan speed selection

Tags: furnace

I am reading a book about HVACs (not finished yet,I might find my answer down the road) and they say that you can increase the speed of your blower (well ..you can adjusted) to obtain the airflow you want. The increase depends on the design of your duct system.
My question is this: when your HVAC technician installs the furnace, for an optimal functioning, does he have to chose between the two-three options available these days or the motor arrives from the manufacturer with a factory default speed and the design of the duct system has to be done around that ?

Comment: In North America it is rare that residential HVAC systems are rigorously designed.  You shouldn't equate what is customarily installed and configured by HVAC technicians as being correct or optimal.  Case in point: The dynamic range of motor speeds available in a typical residential furnace is too small to achieve the optimal speed for the full range of conditions.  You'd need a variable frequency drive to achieve that (I've retrofitted these), but they are expensive so residential equipment generally just uses the crude relays-and-windings method of speed control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how sizing/capacity work from a system design standpoint.  This is the standard but I see a lot of cases where it either wasn't done or wasn't done properly.

1. Ductwork first.  If it's a new construction job, then the ductwork is designed to provide enough airflow to the areas that need it.  If we're replacing a furnace, then usually the ductwork in place is already what's needed, however we (hvac contractor) may make changes if the client isn't happy with the way the system had been working.
2. Based on the ductwork and the size of the living space (and other things like insulation, type of home, etc.) we pick a furnace with an appropriate BTU/hr and CFM (airflow)  output.  Now, some furnaces have two or more stages, which means that the cfm and BTU/hr can change depending on what's needed, but they still have an operational range that is matched to the job.
3. Occasionally, rarely, a client either wants more airflow or the system requires more airflow for one reason or another (for example, if a humidifier is being used) In this case the installer will install the furnace and then increase the blower speed either with DIP switches on the furnace circuit board, by changing the programming in the thermostat (only on special thermostats like carrier's infinity control), or using a different lead connected to the blower motor.  You can also set the fan feature speed this way.  Inside the unit will be a schematic that will have the different blower motor leads labelled with their speeds, usually there's a high, medium high, medium low, and low.

Increasing CFM is pretty much harmless, but be careful decreasing it, because you could damage the furnace.

Comment: So if the ductwork, including air registers was already in place, it shouldn't matter that the basement wasn't finished, the system should have been designed for that existing ductwork.  If you added ductwork or air registers, you may want to increase the blower speed.  You may still have problems with the actual heat capacity though, if the system is undersized it will need to replaced sooner rather than later.

Comment: I think that this is where my problem lies; The duct work is not covered by a finished ceiling and I can not see if there are any dumpers for the ducts in the basement. In basement I have very low air flow compared with upstairs and I think that there is some static pressure in the system because the dumpers preset not to allow too much hot air to go into the basement. Probably they thought that they will save money that way but that might simply overheat the furnace. I have pretty strong air flow upstairs (it is not making a noise yet but it is pretty close to that)

Answer (score 1):

Most blower motors are 3 or 5 speed motors, though it varies by manufacturer.  Typically they come with heat set to use `LOW`, cool and fan set to use `HIGH`.  If it's a 3 speed motor,  the HVAC tech is limited to only adjust to `MED`.  Whereas if it's a 5 speed, the HVAC tech has more flexibility.

In most cases the factory settings are adequate.

Comment: Can't be that simple, my basement was finished long after the furnace was installed and I do not think that the speed was adjusted

Comment: It's rare that the speed has to be adjusted.  The furnace is sized based on the square footage of the conditioned space, and it's very likely that the basement was included in the original calculation.

Comment: So then it was sized for conditioning the main floor. Now that the basement was added the furnace must be undersized.

Comment: Did you dig the basement after the furnace was installed? If not, the furnace was likely sized to include the basement. If you're having trouble heating the finished basement, make sure there are enough return ducts, and that they are open and unobstructed. Also be sure that you insulated the basement well, and properly when you finished it.

Comment: I wonder what could cause the weak air flow to all but one registers.
This one is the only one on the ceiling, all the others are installed at baseboard level....
My installer is not going to deal with that and I am wondering if the new furnace is going to improve the situation down there
One thing that is strange for what was done in the basement is that the ducts have circular section but I believe they were squeezed to fit between drywall and insulation, if you remove the register you can actually see that the section of the pipe is elliptical now

Comment: Sounds like the ducting may have been purely planned, or implemented.  You should contact a local HVAC company to evaluate the installation.

Comment: This is clearly a DIY job, I don't think that I have to contact anybody for that. I am going to use an inspection camera to see deeper inside to see how far the squeezing went. It might have been just to make the transition to the rectangular shape of the registers.

Comment: The duct may not be squeezed.  They make oval ducting that fits in stud cavities.